# PHP Move up echo to fill up empty space

Tags: php, arrays, isnullorempty

How should i do to populate array results into a box. And it should continue to move up to fill the empty space with subsequent search if earlier search resulted in null. And if earlier search is not empty, the subsequent search will be populated in its own position accordingly.

Box
Result 1  // Search on $Arr1 for 'X'
Result 2  // Search on $Arr2 for 'X'. Move up if Result 1 is empty
Result 3  // Search on $Arr3 for 'X'. Move up if Result 1 or 2 is   empty

I tried the following code, but it either doesnt move up to fill the empty space if earlier search was empty nor can it fill up accordingly if more than one result is not empty.

```
<?php

    if (($pos1 = array_search('X', $Arr1, true)) !=== null){
    echo $pos1; ?><br />
    <? 
} else {
  if (($pos2 = array_search('X', $Arr2, true)) !=== null){
            echo $pos2; ?><br /> 
            <?
    } else {
      if (($pos3 = array_search('X', $Arr3, true)) !=== null){
            echo $pos3; ?>
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: Hm i think your compare operator should be !== instead !===

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<?php

if (($pos1 = array_search('X', $Arr1, true)) !== null)
    echo $pos1."<br />";
else if (($pos2 = array_search('X', $Arr2, true)) !== null)
    echo $pos2."<br />"; 
else if (($pos3 = array_search('X', $Arr3, true)) !== null)
    echo $pos3;
```

?>

Comment: `!===` is not a valid php operator. EDIT: I see now, it's the OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it well, but you could try the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
<?php

    echo array_search('X', $Arr1, true)
         ?: array_search('X', $Arr2, true)
         ?: array_search('X', $Arr3, true)
         ?: 'default_value';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Oriol. But I dont think it's a ternary operator. There are total 5 searches from 5 independent arrays. They are all independent of each other. The result of each of these 5 searches is either True or False. 

The problem i'm facing is how i display them on a Table. The code that i'm capable of doesnt allow auto-positioning. Meaning, if Search 1 is null, then result in Search 2 should automatically take the position (row ?) of Search 1. 

Without this, the Table will look odd... where Position 1 (row 1 ?) could be empty, while position 2 (row 2 ?) is filled, position 3 is empty etc...

Comment: My bad due to my limited coding knowledge. I actually found a solution by merging the arrays and use foreach. Thanks everyone.